# unable to run redis with custom config file , I am changing dump.rdb file to resrore.rdb which is a backup from another machine

Tags: database, redis, restore

redis dir is /var/lib/redis and dbfilename is dump.rdb and I have restore.rdb backup whichi is from another machine, I tried to replace dump.rdb with restore.rdb but after starting redis it is overwritten to previous steps , so I have changed my dbfilename to restore.rdb and restarted the server but dbfilename is same as before if check in redis-cli

steps I followed

sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server stop

sudo mv /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb.bak

sudo cp restore.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb

sudo redis-server config/redis.conf

Once server is started dump.rdb is overwritten to previous state. So, instead replace dump.rdb I tried alternative method

sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server stop

sudo cp restore.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb

and then changed dbfilename to restore.rdb in redis.conf

then restarted the redis

sudo redis-server config/redis.conf.

then I entered into redis-cli and to check config and I realised that config hasn't changed

redis server version:
Redis server v=4.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=9435c3c2879311f3

Answer (score 0):

the issue is redis server is running in background even after killing it with below command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server stop
```

so you need to make sure you stop redis server is killed

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server stop

ps aux | grep redis-server | awk '{ print $2 }'| xargs kill -9
```

above commands will kill all redis related server then

```
sudo mv /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb.bak

sudo cp restore.rdb /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb

sudo redis-server config/redis.conf
```